# How to get all super classes of current instance?

Tags: objective-c

Is there possible to track back the class's super classes until ending up with NSObject?

I have some pseudocode over here but it needs some implementations.

```
SomeObject *someObj;

id *currentParent = someObj.Parent;

while (currentParent)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",currentParent);
    currentParent = currentParent.Parent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SomeObject *someObj;
id currentParent = [someObj superclass];

while (currentParent)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",currentParent);
    currentParent = [currentParent superclass];
}
```